# find quotient ring of $K[X,Y,Z] / (X, Y(1-X))$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a field. I'm seeking some hints to find  quotient ring of $K[X,Y,Z] / (X, Y(1-X))$.

Is there any general method to solve this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case $X$ and $Y$ map to zero in $K[X,Y,Z]/(X,Y(1-X))$
so the ring is the same as $K[X,Y,Z]/(X,Y)$ which is isomorphic to $K[Z]$.

In more complicated examples, one might use *Groebner bases* to understand
a general ideal, and the corresponding quotient ring.